Google drive api Error, We are Sorry, but your computer or network may be sending automated queries
 headers: {
                                      'x-goog-api-client': 'gdcl/7.2.0 gl-node/20.17.0',
                                      'content-type': 'multipart/related; boundary=1a372e33-1c3d-4783-b5b0-2d787811e93d',
                                      'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip',
                                      'User-Agent': 'google-api-nodejs-client/7.2.0 (gzip)',
                                      Authorization: '<<REDACTED> - See `errorRedactor` option in `gaxios` for configuration>.'
                                    },

Error:
 status: 429,
                                    statusText: 'Too Many Requests',
                                    request: {
                                      responseURL: 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?fields=id&uploadType=multipart'
                                    }

Same code request is working in local, but not in production.
We are on aws and using ngnix.
This issue came out of nowhere and it was working earlier.
I have checked in gcp and we never it the rate limit and also increase the rate limit.
usage graph from gcp:

This issue is only on this route:
'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?fields=id&uploadType=multipart'
All other routes are working
I have been trying to fix this issue for quite few days.
Please let me know if anyone can help here.
Nothing worked for so far.

It appears to be an issue between AWS and GCP, specifically the AWS US regions.  We had the issue on us-west-2 when trying to create or update items using the Google Drive API.  The issue was reported on Sept. 26 then again Sept. 29-30.
You can also check out Google drive API returns 429 error to create files inside us-east-1 AWS but not in other zone
It appears to be resolved as of 16:00 UTC.

Yes, we are in us-east-1, and I just checked—it's working now. We are thinking of shifting our project to another region for a few days until we are sure that this problem is resolved.

Here is the Google issue tracker for this problem, which has been happening intermittently since 9/26. Only write commands seem to be affected. As of today, Google has at least a temporary solution in place.
(I would add this as a comment to the accepted answer but don't have enough reputation.)
